# Align items in a div when div breaks up to 2 rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

What I have:

A navbar, with a group of buttons on the right-hand side.
When the navbar becomes too small (e.g. on a smartphone), the div divides the two buttons up into 2 rows. In that state, I want to align the 2 buttons inside the div to the right side, but no matter what I try, Bootstrap always aligns the items to the left side, as shown in the picture. (outline just for illustration)

Good:

[image]

Bad:

[image]

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand d-flex justify-content-around" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #202020;">
  <div class="">
    <a class="btn btn-orange m-1" href="./projects">Projekte</a>
  </div>
  <a href="./">
    <image class="my-1" id="logo" src="./res/fnbg-logo6.svg" alt="FNBG Logo">
  </a>
  <div class="border me-2">
    <a class="btn btn-orange m-1 align-self-end" target="_blank" href="mailto:a@bc.de">a@bc.de</a>
    <a class="btn btn-orange m-1 align-self-end" target="_blank" href="https://linkedin.com/in/abcde/">LinkedIn</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: note that `<image>` as a tag does not exist. The correct tag is `<img>`. Alternatively, you have a `<picture>`-tag (which also requires an `<img>`-tag) as a responsive solution to use a `srcset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the buttons `div` it's own flex container with `d-flex`, then add the `justify-content-end` class (aligns to the right) and `flex-wrap` class so that they wrap as desired.

More info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand d-flex justify-content-around" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #202020;">
  <div class="">
    <a class="btn btn-orange m-1" href="./projects">Projekte</a>
  </div>
  <a href="./">
    <img class="my-1" id="logo" src="./res/fnbg-logo6.svg" alt="FNBG Logo">
  </a>
  <div class="border me-2 d-flex justify-content-end flex-wrap">
    <a class="btn btn-orange m-1" target="_blank" href="mailto:a@bc.de">a@bc.de</a>
    <a class="btn btn-orange m-1 align-self-end" target="_blank" href="https://linkedin.com/in/abcde/">LinkedIn</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```